# uilabel.layer.backgroundcolor does not work in CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: cakeyframeanimation

I'm not sure why the following code does not make label's background color change. I'm thinking whether label's layer can not change background color in animation. Hoping someone can give me an answer. Thanks a lot!

```
    CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];

    animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id) [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,
                        (id) [UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                        (id) [UIColor blueColor].CGColor, nil];

    animation.duration = 3.0f;
    animation.autoreverses = NO;

    [updateRecordLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the keyPath for the animation. You can create animation:

```
1.   CAKeyframeAnimation *theAnimation=[CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];

2.CAKeyframeAnimation *theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
  [theAnimation setKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
```

I think you misunderstanding 'addAnimation:animation forKey:@"backgroundColor"]' forkey, the key is the 'name' of the animation, but not the keypath for the property you will be animated.